# Magento 1.5.1 crashing after running index category/product association?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a magento install, 1.5.1 with eight different multi-stores enabled and about 1,000 products. When I run indexing for category/products association the admin hangs and does not respond for 20+ minutes. Occasionally the server crashes entirely.

The server should have sufficient resources to run this index. Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Trying running the reindex from the ssh shell.  Change into your home directory where you magento files are and then into the /shell directory.  From there run:

php indexer.php --reindexall

And look for any errors that display.

Comment: Or to be exact php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product

Comment: Check any server logs for the domain as well.  I would have a timeout on your webserver as well.  You don't want requests to hang like that for so long.  I usually recommend 3-5 minutes.